# EJB + JSP: Cannot create the Remote Object from the Home interface

Tags: java, ejb, rmi, remoteobject

I'm a newbie in the J2EE/EJB field and I'm following some basic examples. I have implemented a very simple class that sums 2 number. I have the home and remote interfaces and the Enterprise Bean (stateless) itself.

```
Adder.java //Remote interface
AdderHome.java //Home interface
AdderBean.java //The EJB class
```

When testing it as an EJB application, everything works perfectly. But now, I'd like to test it as a JSP page but I get an error (actually there's no output) at the point in which the remote interface is instantiated from the home interface.

In time: I'm using J2EE 1.4 with JBoss 4.

Here's the code of the JSP page. It's supposed to only print out one line.

```
<%@page import="javax.naming.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Properties" %>
<%@page import="com.lucasmariano.*" %>

<%
        //Preparing the properting to be put in the InitialContext
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "localhost:1099");

        try {
            //Get an Initial Context               
            InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(properties);
            System.out.println("got context");               

            //get a reference to the bean
            Object ref = jndiContext.lookup("Adder");
            System.out.println("got reference");


            //Get a reference to this to the bean's home interface
            AdderHome home = (AdderHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ref, AdderHome.class);
            out.println("GETTING OBJECT <BR />");

            //create an Adder object from the Home interface

            //######  HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!  #######
            Adder adder = home.create();
            out.println("ADDER OBJECT CREATED <BR />");
            out.println("2 + 5 = " + adder.add(2,5));

        }catch(Exception e ){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
  %>
```

Do I need to add some new value to my web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Duffymo. What you're doing is Just Wrong.

EJB is a great technology, but EJB2 was downright evil. It was designed in an ivory tower with only a single goal: make life of developers as difficult as possible.

In this time and day there is no reason to *start* with EJB2. The only reason for learning EJB2 is when you have to maintain some old legacy app written with EJB2 (but then I suggest to find another job).

Despite only 1 version higher, EJB3 is a completely different thing. It's easy, lightweight, very logical and came to being with a lot of community feedback. But even EJB3 is quite old. The current version is EJB3.1, which can be used with Glassfish v3.1, JBoss AS 6 or Resin 4 (with Resin you'll get EJB3.1 lite+).

Comment: Indeed I'm following a book published in 2002. But I didn't imagine things got totally changed in this way (even if it's about programming language and I know it changes a lot in the course of time). I'll look for some materials about EJB3 and EJB3.1 to be uptodate. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend going this way.  Scriptlets in JSPs are frowned upon.

Which Java EE app server are you using?  I hope it's Java EE 5 or higher.  I wonder if you're starting with a older EJB standard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if it's my first app using EJB + JSP I'm pretty aware that that's not the best way to proceed. I only want to see things working. Anyway I'm using J2EE 1.4 with JBoss 4. I'm also using Netbeans 6.9.1. In time: Do I need to add something to my web.xml regarding the home/remote interfaces?

Comment: Maybe an <ejb-ref> is the tonic: http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2010/07/sample-webxml-servlet-30-with-ejb-ref.html